# Wordpress returning wrong image size after changing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fetching the featured image of a post by the function

```
the_post_thumbnail('medium');
```

It was fetching the correct image before but I had changed the size of medium from 300 to 400 in wordpress media settings and regenerated all the images. The image with size 400 is present and got generated. But now it continues to fetch the 300 resolution image instead of 400.

How can I fix this and make it fetch the 400 size image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use this line of code  add **function.php**

```
add_image_size( 'homeFeatured',300, 300, array('center','center') );
```

> using this get the file in a specific size of the file.

```
<?php  the_post_thumbnail('homeFeatured') ?>
```

Comment: I have already defined the sizes in wordpress settings and do not want to define an additional size. Because then I will have to regenerate the sizes for all 10k images in my media

Comment: you use regenerate plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: I do not want to declare an additional image size but use the existing wordpress medium size for 400 resolution